# How to return a s that has the maximum Sum value in the list

Tags: python

I need to create a maxSequence() function ,that has a user input for a list and  it  takes the input  list as an argument and it returns a sublist whose values sequence gibve us the maximum sum in the list .

So if we call the maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]).
It should return  :  6: [4, -1, 2, 1]

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm

Comment: Thanks @user2357112, I was sure it was combinatorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You have to brute force it.</s>
Edit: There are faster [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm) than my brute force solution. (thanks @[user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)
)

Construct all sublists and check which has the biggest sum. To construct all sublists start at `start=0` and `end=start+1`, then increase `end` until the result is the whole list, repeat that step with an increased `start` etc:

```
a = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]

max = sum(a)
l = a[:]
for start in range(len(a)):
    for end in range(start, len(a)):
        s = sum(a[start:end+1])
        if s > max:
            max = s
            l = a[start:end+1]
print(max, l)
```

Result:

```
6 [4, -1, 2, 1]
```

The lists you check are (in that order):

```
[-2]
[-2, 1]
[-2, 1, -3]
[-2, 1, -3, 4]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
[1]
[1, -3]
[1, -3, 4]
[1, -3, 4, -1]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
[1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
[-3]
[-3, 4]
[-3, 4, -1]
[-3, 4, -1, 2]
[-3, 4, -1, 2, 1]
[-3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
[-3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
[4]
[4, -1]
[4, -1, 2]
[4, -1, 2, 1]
[4, -1, 2, 1, -5]
[4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
[-1]
[-1, 2]
[-1, 2, 1]
[-1, 2, 1, -5]
[-1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
[2]
[2, 1]
[2, 1, -5]
[2, 1, -5, 4]
[1]
[1, -5]
[1, -5, 4]
[-5]
[-5, 4]
[4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man , it worked like a charm .  I  only want ot ask now how can we change the default List of A , with a list that we're going to give to the program on every iteration. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Also i'd like to contain the whole code under a maxSequence() function .